# Where to put helper methods used in events for multiple Meteor templates

Tags: meteor, project-structure

I know that I can access methods across files by omitting var, but what is the "best practices" project directory structure for defining helper methods that are used by template events across different templates.

For example, I have:

template1.js:

```
Template.template1.events({
  'event': function () {
    helper();
   }
});
```

template2.js:

```
Template.template2.events({
  'event': function () {
    helper();
   }
});
```

Comment: Don't you want to just register a universal helper with Template.registerHelper(name, function) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One problem with Meteor's "share code across files with globals" approach is that when you're looking at the file where a function is used, you don't know where the function is defined. I prefer to define a single global variable in each file which needs to export variables. That variable has the same name as the file, with an initial capital (or some other naming convention which identifies it as an "export object"). Exports are stored as properties of that object. So you might create a file named `globalHelpers.js`:

```
GlobalHelpers = {};
GlobalHelpers.helper = function () {
    // ...
};
```

And then use it in other files with `GlobalHelpers.helper()`. If you look at this code later, you know to look in `globalHelpers.js` to find the `helper` function.

If a file exports a single class or collection then it's okay to just use that object as the export object. So instead of `things.js` with `Things = {}; Things.Things = new Mongo.Collection...` you can just do `Things = new Mongo.Collection...`.

You might need to place the file in a `lib` directory so it loads before the other files.

Don't register it with `Template.registerHelper` unless you want to call it directly from templates with `{{ }}` calls.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest defining such functions in `/client/scripts/globalHelpers.js`

Example:

```
Template.registerHelper('foo',function(arg1,arg2){
  return arg1 + arg2;
});
```

Then you can use this function from anywhere by prefixing it with `Blaze._globalHelpers.`:

```
var result = Blaze._globalHelpers.foo(param1, param2);
```